# Frame is not responding while imageAi detection

Tags: image-processing, python-asyncio, python-3.7, video-processing

when i run the program, i frame is hanging and not responding. i am using imageAI package for video detection. what i want to do, is to show the video stream while the video detection is running.
and idea?

```
import cv2
from imageai.Detection import VideoObjectDetection
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
    _, frame = camera.read()

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    plt.show()

    k = cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

    detector = VideoObjectDetection()
    detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
    detector.setModelPath("yolo.h5")
    detector.loadModel()

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    plt.show()

    video_path = detector.detectObjectsFromVideo(camera_input=camera,
                                output_file_path="traffic_detected"
                                , frames_per_second=20, log_progress=True, minimum_percentage_probability=30)


    print(video_path)
    # cv2.imshow('frame',frame)



camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```